# How to make tensor connect to model in computational graph when using pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I use pytorch to construct following codes:

```py
        gru_output, gru_hn = self.gru(x)
        # Decoder (Graph Adjacency Reconstruction)
        pred = self.decoder(gru_output[data_batch_idx, -1, :])  # gru_output[-1] => only take last time-step
        pred_graph_adj = pred.reshape(1, -1) if data_batch_idx == 0 else torch.cat((pred_graph_adj, pred.reshape(1, -1)), dim=0)

        if output_type == "discretize":
            bins = torch.tensor(self.model_cfg['output_bins'])
            num_bins = len(bins)-1
            tmp_tensor = torch.bucketize(pred_graph_adj, bins, right=True).to(torch.float64)
            tmp_tensor = torch.clamp(tmp_tensor, min=1, max=num_bins, out=tmp_tensor)
            tmp_tensor.requires_grad = True
            discretize_values = np.linspace(-1, 1, num_bins)
            for discretize_tag, discretize_value in zip(torch.unique(tmp_tensor), discretize_values):
                tmp_tensor = torch.where(tmp_tensor == discretize_tag, discretize_value, tmp_tensor)
            discretize_pred_graph_adj = tmp_tensor
```

I find out that in the computational graph, `pred_graph_adj` is attach to `self.decoder`.

And `discretize_pred_graph_adj` doesn't connect to  `self.decoder`.

But `discretize_pred_graph_adj` is coming from `tmp_tensor` and `tmp_tensor` is coming from `torch.bucketize(pred_graph_adj, bins, right=True)`.

Here is my questions:

1. Why doesn't `discretize_pred_graph_adj` connect to `self.decoder`?
2. How to make them connect together?